# php Google Calendar exclude read-only calendars from the list

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I'm displaying a list of calendars where users can choose from to create new events.
I'm testing with my own account and one of the calendars is read-only, then when I try to create a new event in it, logicaly, returns an error message saying it's read-only.
How can i exclude read-only calendars from the list?

```
function getGoogleCalendars()
{
    $html .= validateGoogleSession();
    if($html == "")
    {
        $client = getAuthSubHttpClient();
        $calendars = getCalendarList($client);

        if(!empty($calendars))
        {
            $html .= "<h1>Select Calendars</h1><br\>";
            $html .=  "<ul><br\>";
            foreach ($calendars as $calendar) 
            {
                //var_dump($calendar);
                $html .=  "<li>" . $calendar->title->text ." <input type='checkbox' name='gcalendar' value='".$calendar->content->src."' /></li><br\>";
            }
            $html .= "</ul><br\>";
            $html .= "<label>Alert: </label><input id='alert' type='checkbox' name='reminder[]' value='alert' />";
            $html .= "<label>E-mail: </label><input id='email' type='checkbox' name='reminder[]' value='email' />";
            $html .= "<label>Minutes before: </label><input id='minutes' type='input' name='minutes' value=15 />";
            $html .= "<button class='add-event'>Add Event</button>";
        }
    }
    return $html;
}
```

**Edit**

This is the error I'm having:

**Fatal error**:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with message 'Expected response code 200, got 403
This feed is read-only'

and this is the calendar feed:

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/%23contacts%40group.v.calendar.google.com/private/full
```

Since it's full and it's not basic could be or not read-only :s

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of search in google i think i found the solution, atleast works in my example:

```
if($calendar->accesslevel->value != "read" && $calendar->accesslevel->value != "freebusy" && $calendar->accesslevel->value != "none")
    $html .=  "<li>" . $calendar->title->text ." <input type='checkbox' name='gcalendar' value='".$calendar->content->src."' /></li><br\>";
```

**Edit**

After some more search i found the meaning of the several access levels that could be usefull:

**none**
    Current user has no access to the calendar.
**read**
    Current user has read-only access to the calendar.
**freebusy**
    Current user can see only the free/busy information on the calendar, not the details of events.
**editor**
    Current user has full edit access to the calendar, except that they can't change the calendar's access control settings.
**owner**
    Current user has full owner access to the calendar.
**root**
    Available only in Google Apps domains. User is a domain administrator, and therefore has full owner access to the calendar regardless of access control settings.

I hope this helps someone else because it wasn't easy to find the answer.